# Recyclerview & Cardview (Horizontal Layout) within a ScrollView/NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to have nested scrollview and have two recyclerview inside it. The trouble I am facing is that when I try to scroll horizontally the screen goes up and down, even though my action is on a recyclerview. How can I ensure that if I swipe horizontally, the screen would not scroll up and down and if I swipe horizontally on the recyclerview, the horizontal cardview should scroll.

Any way to achieve it?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue. The OnTouch is not very smooth when used this way. I've currently using it the same way, but hopefully there is a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in my app. But it's true that sometimes is not very smooth and when you try to scroll horizontally it just goes up and down.

I'm using a NestedScrollView with several RecyclerViews scrolling horizontally inside.

Anything to make it a bit more responsive would be nice.